# How to make LTSP log into the Windows 7 VM

Tags: 12.04, server, windows-7, kvm-virtualization, ltsp

I have managed to install Ubuntu server and [Mythbuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythbuntu) and a remote front-end. Now I think it could be nice to integrate my Windows machine with the server and use [Linux Terminal Server Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Terminal_Server_Project) (LTSP) to log directly into the Windows 7 desktop. Can it be done and if yes how do I do it?

I have the Windows license and will be the only user.

To be more precise: I would like to be able to set up a LTSP client from where I can log into a Windows 7 session running in [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) or similar.

I have not made the Windows VM yet, but I am trying to figure out how to log into it automatically via LTSP. The Ubuntu server is up and running and I have made normal Ubuntu VMs using KVM. I just didn't want to move the existing Windows license before I had some OK odds for it to work.

Comment: You didnt explained your question, I undertanded that you have windows 7 as virtual machine on UBUNTU LTS server ? probably be virtualbox ? and you want to access your virtualmachine windows 7 remotely ?

Comment: When I have a good idea about how to do it I would move my Windows installation into KVM. My question is  How do I make it possible what VM to boot into from a client.

Answer (score 1):

you have to know the ip of the windows desktop.

follow this guide to enable remote desktop on windows : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/

Then you have to use the remote desktop protocol of windows with ltsp :

Official LTSP Guide : http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Integration#Rdesktop

you have normaly rdesktop installed on your thin client image. However if this doesn't work think to change your client chroot to have rdesktop.

In the guide they takl about SCREEN07, if you want to have the usual LTSP and Windows you have to define your SCREEN numbers (1 to 12). For changing screen just do a CTRL+ALT+FXX with XX being the number of your defined screen.

Best regards